# Regular Expression for validating Website URL in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, regex, expression

What is the regular expression for validating Website URL in SQL Server?

here's my query:

```
UPDATE INE
SET INE.ErrorDetails = INE.ErrorDetails +'WebSite not in correct format. (ex.www.testmail.com)'
FROM IntEmployees INE
Where 
    INE.WebSite Not like 'what is the expression for URL ??'
AND
    ISNULL(INE.InterfaceType_120,0) = 1
AND 
    INE.Status = 1
```

Comment: May be this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23432166/validate-url-with-a-check-constraint

Answer (score 0):

.... Where Website Not Like '%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%.[a-z][a-z]%'